# Which word order is correct, "explain why I am" or "explain why am I"?

Tags: modal-verbs, word-order, questions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I was trying to formulate a question yesterday I used the second sentence, however, I keep wondering if that was correct.

> Can someone explain to me why I am ...? or

> Can someone explain to me why am I ...?

Is "why I am" even valid in any sentence context?

Comment: ***Why I am** voting to close this question is because it's a duplicate*.

Comment: it's not a duplicate, you edited it to look like duplicate but it isn't

Comment: Of course it's a duplicate! There's only one principle involved here - ***Why am I here*** is a ***question***, and ***Why I am here*** is a ***noun phrase***.

Answer (score 2):

A statement giving a reason might be

> He is happy because it is warm.

A question might be formed by replacing the reason with the question word. Introducing an auxiliary verb "does", inverting the subject and auxiliary. Then fronting the word "why":

He is happy <s>because it is warm</s> why. → He is happy why → Is he happy why? →

> Why is he happy?

If you don't invert the subject you get a content clause, not a full sentence.  It can stand in for the content in a sentence, in place of a noun phrase or prepositional phrase. It means the same as "the reason that ..."

> Why he is happy is because it is warm.  = The reason that he is happy is because it is warm.

So in your example, you need a content clause to mean

> Can someone explain to me the reason that I am ...

So you should use the non-question clause "why I am"

Answer (score 2):

The question form is inverted:
Why **am I** so stubborn?

Statement clause:

Please tell me **why I am so stubborn**.

This pattern is true to all English utterances:

- Why **does he drive** his car so fast? [question form]
- I will tell you *why he drives* his car so fast. [clause]

Inversions are for questions and statements do not use inversions.

However, there are times in speech, where a question is given by intonation and not by inversion.

Please tell me why I am so stubborn?

Often, these are rhetorical questions.